# Is it bad to have if statements without else statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I was just curious to know if its a bad thing to have an if(){} construct without an else statement in java.

Comment: No..................................

Comment: No, but some people prefer `else { /*do nothing*/ }` for documentation.

Comment: It is only bad if you need to do something when the condition is false.

Comment: Maybe! Do you need to do something when the `if` does not succeed?

Comment: No, absolutely not! In fact, it is very common to have an `if` without an `else` when there is no specific activity that needs to be performed when the condition is false.

Comment: @Floris Not always.  `someFunction() { if(someFlag) { return someValue; } return someOtherValue; }`

Comment: @nhgrif ...which is wrong on many levels :-)

Comment: @assylias I've seen it.  I don't do it myself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What's wrong with it exactly?  I don't do it myself, seems slightly pointless, but what's explicitly wrong about it?

Comment: Not always but there could be situation where it makes sense to have if else instead of multiple if.

Comment: @VivekVermani `if else` situation is vastly different from an `if if` situation...

Comment: my point was that there could be situation where else can resolve unnecessary checking another if condition. Instead of check if(x>0) and then if(x>5) , it makes more sense to put it like if(x>5), else if(x>1). as it will save evaluating if(x>1) everytime. Hope it makes sense.All If Else Statements can be replaced with multiple ifs but many a times they shouldn't be.

Comment: @nhgrif - from a code readability / maintainability perspective it would be better to do `if(condition) { retval = this; } else {retval = that; } return retval;` . Having multiple points from which to return a value sometimes makes sense, but I think it should only be done if it makes the code more readable. I will, for example, "break early" from a loop with a return statement (rather than playing with flags); but not a simple `if` statement.

Comment: @nhgrif Putting an `else` branch where it is not required by the logic behind the code of your program sends a wrong message to the reader. It also confuses people who maintain your program into thinking that there's a possibility that they may need to add some code to the `else` branch. Compiler designers go through a lot of trouble to enable `else`-less `if`s for a reason - there are situations when the logic could not possibly need an `else`, now or at some later time. Adding an `else` for "documentation" tells a wrong story.

Answer (score 12):

No of course not. There are several times when you only need an if statement without a corresponding else.

Comment: Yeah, I figured thanks a lot. I really don't need to to anything else in my case but anyway THANk you!!!!!!!!!!!!!