# How To Write Two If Statements Into One Single Line (Ternary Operator)?

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

How do I write the following 2 line if-statments into one single line of code:

```
  if (s1.length() == 0)
       return "hello";
  if (s2.length() == 0)
       return "goodbye";
```

I want to learn how to write it in the Ternary-Operator format:

```
  if ? then : else
```

but I don't have an "else" in my example PLUS i have two "if" statements so it's confusing me.

Is it possible to combine these 2 if-statements into one line of code?

Comment: if you don´t have any "`else`", as of a return after the `if`´s, your code wouldn´t compile as it would expect a return at some point... but it could look like this: `return s1.length() == 0?"hello":s2.length()==0?"goodbye":"yourElse"`;

Comment: I do have a "main" return for the overall method:  return; which just exits the function.

Comment: Also my function doesn't need an "else" -- nor does every "if" in java is necessarily needed to be accompanied by an else:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081558/is-it-bad-to-have-if-statements-without-else-statements

Comment: This wouldn´t compile either, as of my guess, it would throw you a compiler error `This method must return a result of type String`. And yeah an `if` doesn´t need an `else`, but a `String methodName()` needs a `String` return, which you wouldn´t provide without a default `return`.

Comment: Like the answers say, to use a ternary operator you need to know what you're going to return if neither one of those is 0.  But I think you also need to question your premise: why is it important to combine things into one line of code?  You don't get improved performance by having fewer lines in your program.  Much of the time, attempts to squeeze things into fewer lines of code result in programs that are harder for another person to figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but I don't have an "else" in my example

In order to write this with the conditional operator, we **need** the "else" case at the end. So:

```
if (s1.length() == 0)
    return "hello";
if (s2.length() == 0)
    return "goodbye";
return "neither";
```

Without that final value, you cannot write this with a conditional operator.

*With* that final value, you can, but I wouldn't recommend it from a readability or maintenance perspective:

```
return s1.length() == 0 ? "hello" : s2.length() == 0 ? "goodbye" : "neither";
```

You can see how the "then" and "else" of an `if/else` pretty much map directly into the second and third operands of the conditional.

---

Fun fact: It's properly called the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). It's commonly referred to as "the ternary operator," but really it's just ***a*** ternary operator (an operator that accepts three operands, just like a binary operator accepts two operands and a unary operator accepts one). It's the only ternary operator Java currently has, but in theory, someday, it could have others...

Comment: Just to point out that in the comment, OP says he as a return at the end so this match the answer. And from this, it easy to write it just like a ternary using if - else if - else like `if(s1...) ... else if (s2 ...) else ...`  (just a middle step being more readable)

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation!  This helped me understand Ternary/conditional operations better.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly like

```
return (s1.length() == 0) ? "hello" : (s2.length() == 0 ? "goodbye" : "something when none is satisfied");
```